# Marking nodes as visited when tranversing object hirearchy

Tags: java, reflection, data-structures

I made a small Java program that uses reflection to inspect an object's fields and recursively transverse its structure in order to build a tree of all its members, similar to what the debugger does when inspecting a variable.

The big problem is that sometimes circular references appear. My tree becomes a graph! Then my program enters in an infinite loop and eventually throws StackOverflow exception (oh, the irony!)

My question is... how can "mark" an arbitrary object as visited in order to implement any standard graph transversal algorithm? I can't use hashCode() since any object can be used as input and different objects can return identical hash codes. Any clue?

Thanks in advanced!

```
public class ClassHierarchyItem {

private boolean parent;
private String id;
private String parentId;
private String name;
private String type;
private String value;

public ClassHierarchyItem(boolean parent, String id, String parentId, String name, String type, String value){
    this.parent = parent;
    this.id = id;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
}

public String toString() {
    return (isParent() ? "+" : "") + name + " - " + type + " - " + value + " [id=" + id + ", pId=" + parentId + "]";  
}
//Getters and setters follow (cutted)
}

public class ClassHierarchyNavigator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i = 123;

    // Fails with StackOverflow exception (some reference inside Integer points back to base object)
    System.out.println(renderHirearchy(i));
}

public static List<ClassHierarchyItem> renderHirearchy(Object o) {

    List<ClassHierarchyItem> items = new ArrayList<ClassHierarchyItem>();

    boolean parent = (o.getClass().getDeclaredFields().length > 0 && !o.getClass().isPrimitive() && o.getClass() != String.class)
            || o.getClass().isArray();

    buildObjectTree(items, o, parent, "root", o.getClass().getName(), "r", "");

    return items;
}

private static boolean isParent(Field field) {

    return (field.getClass().getDeclaredFields().length > 0 && !field.getType().isPrimitive() && field.getType() != String.class)
            || field.getType().isArray();
}

private static void buildObjectTree(List<ClassHierarchyItem> items, Object object, boolean parent,
        String objectName, String objectType, String objectId, String parentId) {

    long subItemCount = 1;
    String value = object == null ? "null" : object.toString();

    ClassHierarchyItem item = new ClassHierarchyItem(parent, objectId, parentId, objectName, objectType,
            value.substring(0, value.length() > 80 ? 80 : value.length()));
    items.add(item);

    if (!parent) {
        return;
    }

    // if (isArray) {
    // do_array_treatment
    // } else {
    for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object child;
        try {
            child = field.get(object);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            continue;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            continue;
        }

        String childId = objectId + "-" + subItemCount++;
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        boolean childIsParent = child != null && !"this$0".equals(fieldName) && isParent(field);

        buildObjectTree(items, child, childIsParent, fieldName, field.getType().getName(), childId, objectId);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: post code where you save inspected fields..

Comment: There. I uploaded the code. This is just a pre-alpha test version! It's quick and dirty code!

Answer (score 0):

Use a hashtable data structure, such as a HashMap, and use the objects as keys. Indeed, some hashs will collide, but collision resolution is the root idea behind hashtables: every hash leads to a bucket containing every key/value pair with the same hash, thus allowing you to retrieve your objects.

However, if your objects also reimplemented equals() so that two objects may be equals, that's an issue, since the collision resolution method won't be able to differentiate two keys from the same bucket. If so, design your own hastable by using hashcode() to get the hash but the language "==" comparison to compare the objects by memory address.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't do that, since the objects I'm traversing can be of any type! Look at my (dirty) code, I just updated the original post.